# Audio Enhancements not working since 1909 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1909

I have posted this on both Reddit & as feedback via the Windows 10 Feedback app and have had no responses in the several weeks that I have had this issue.

Some weeks ago I updated to Windows 10 v1909 and since then I have been unable to use Audio Enhancements via the

> Sound -> Device -> Advanced -> Enable Audio Enhancements

option via Control Panel.

Enabling Audio Enhancements causes audio to mute, only when I disable Audio Enhancements is when audio finally returns.

My audio driver is Realtek UWD SONICSTUDIO III TP W10 64 VER6018666.
My audio source is via Optical which goes to a DAC and amplifier.
I am also using Realtek's `Audio Console` application to configure the equalizer.

I have tried:

1. Uninstalling my audio driver
2. Upgrading my audio driver
3. Downgrading/reverting the v1909 update

I am trying to avoid a reinstall.
Has anybody encountered this same issue, and knows how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Against my own wish I decided to reinstall Windows 10 which resolved this issue.

I am not going to mark this as the answer because there may be a proper solution to this, I ran out of ideas.